# Where does the burden of responsibility and support from shared components/services lie?

Tags: open-source, web-services, component

This is an issue that has somewhat been raised by the left-pad incident with NPM but I'm also interested in it from an internal business perspective.

For example imagine an organisation with 3 teams, A, B and C. Team A build a component for their site, it fits their needs perfectly because they built it themselves. Team B have very similar requirements so decide to just simply integrate the component into their site. Team C do not adopt the component.

Now a few months down the line Team A modifies the component for a new requirement, either technical or not, and this breaks Team B's implementation of the component.

Does team B have a right to ask Team A to support a legacy version? Should Team B fork the component and customise it only once it has been broken, or should they have done this at first just in case?

To make things more complicated imagine they aren't components but live services, so now Team A has broken Team B's live site. How does that affect the scenario?

Just interested to see where people views are on responsibility and support models in an open source community, be it public or private.

Comment: `Does team B have a right to ask Team A to support a legacy version?`  -Team B can ask Team A anything they like. In turn, Team A can make any decision they like regarding Team B's request.  Open-source works for the same reason any relationship works; the participants decide whether or not the benefits outweigh the risks, and agree (or not) on behaviors that support the benefits.

Comment: I guess thats what I'm interested in, I'm keen to encourage re use but the risks seem very high if a component being changed effectively breaks a website and the team in charge of the website has little to no control on fixing it. And yet the team that created the component similarly didn't sign up to offer support to anyone so it probably ends in no sharing occurring and both teams building their own component,

Comment: One of the reasons you go with open source is that (in principle) you can maintain the component yourself if the group maintaining the component goes belly-up.  You don't usually have that choice with commercial products.

Comment: But what if the group maintaining it changes direction? Or changes I/O support or what API their using or any other technical change that is integral to your implementation?

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to do something else, won't you?

Comment: That is the question. Then what is the benefit of using that component at all if I will have to rebuild it anyway. Surely within the organisation it's better for Team B to immediately fork and begin maintaining their own component?

Comment: That is one possible choice, yes.

Comment: With components, you're under no obligation to pick up the new version.  With services, the organization must have a SLA in place.

Comment: I believe forking is the worst possible thing to do. This is not working DRY, and as a company, it should want to save as much time on the development process. The component should have been developed with robustness in mind and **very important** - there should be a team dedicated to **shared** components, that maintain these components and may create new ones, or accept ones from other teams, at an agreed-upon interface and set of rules for making components which is defined by the company (by the components-team).

Answer (score 2):

The burden of responsibility ultimately lies with whoever is responsible for coordinating the work of these teams.  (Someone at every company is responsible for that, whether they recognize it or not.)

From a technical standpoint, team B should have notified team A that they were using team A's component.  Normally, this would make team A rather proud of themselves.  Subsequently, team A should have treated their API as public, evolving it in a backward-compatible way as much as practically possible, making use of conventions like [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) to help team B set their expectations, and deprecating obsolete features before removing them to help team B plan ahead.

Comment: The key part is the stakeholder entity that is in-charge of coordination between teams and has some authority. Without a single authority above all teams, ego and chaos might emerge. When internal politics/ego comes into play, it is time for the top entity to call the shots and fix the situation in the best possible way.