# Good approaches for sharing reusable components between teammates

Tags: code-reuse, component

Question: Talking about software development, how to provide good approaches to achieve a repository of reusable components inside a project?

Context: Working on a team of 10 coworkers may be very interesting but could be also unorganized. Duplicated services, components, in other words, shareable code. Documenting and promoting the use of these code can be very hard. Are there any known approaches to achieve full modular project even when working on multiple teammates? I understand that this question could be too generic, but if you had been passed through work with multiple workers, you must understand what is this.

It's important to say that this approach should be free of any technology. But, examples related to Angular or Node.js, or web-related technologies are more than welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you structure your shared code so that it is "re-findable" for new developers?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/34354/how-do-you-structure-your-shared-code-so-that-it-is-re-findable-for-new-develo)

Comment: see also: [How do you keep track of what classes and functions your team has written?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196628/how-do-you-keep-track-of-what-classes-and-functions-your-team-has-written)

Comment: Best approach: split the team into two smaller teams of five, and make sure each sub-team develops an isolated part of the product, separated by clearly defined interfaces from the part of the other team. Let each of the team create and use their own reusable components, and live with the fact one team might develop something the other team did also, at least to some degree. The reduced communication overhead will most probably outweigh the drawbacks of this duplicate component development.

Comment: linked - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/326404/206310

Answer (score 3):

The usual good practices apply.

Whether it's a future you, a team of 2, a team of 10, an overseas team or whatever, write code that is

- Modular
- Easy to read
- Well named
- Well tested
- etc.

With classes and methods that are

- Short
- Single purpose
- Unit tested
- etc.

With team members that

- Physically work together most of the time
- Use a code review system
- Respect each other
- Care about quality
- Have a good work-life balance

Comment: The last couple of points are the most important – talking to each other and sharing what you're currently working on makes it easy to spot opportunities for sharing. “Oh, I recently did something similar for X, maybe you can adapt that code.” That's the difference between a *team* of 10 devs, and 10 devs sitting in an office, each doing their thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just one aspect I haven't seen mentioned in the related questions/answers:

Depending on the size of your project team and the amount of base coding already available, it might make sense to dedicate a certain percentage (10-20%) of your developers to writing basic/fundamental/re-use library code. Those guys should have enough hindsight and experience to be able to decide "what's generic/re-usable" enough to be worth picking up.

Other members of the team working on more specialized parts of the app might then be able to "order" base functionality they consider useful for all parts of the project from this sub-team or hand over basic re-usable parts to those guys. If there is time, you can also have these people hunt for re-usable components in the overall code base to take over into the "general support libraries" for further development, generalisation and (important!) documentation.

This (at least somewhat) avoids spreading responsibility for the basic bits and pieces over the whole code and developer base and can ensure proper documentation. Also ensures a steadily growing library for the others to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Bit:

https://github.com/teambit/bit

It's an open source project that enables you to turn any subset of files from your source code a reusable component and create a playlist-like collection without setting up new libraries/packages.
Components can be shared with your team and across projects (example: https://bitsrc.io/bit/movie-app#components).

Enjoy